# can't pass pageContext to post template in gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, prismic.io

im struggle with pass context to component template,
when i console.log the "props" in post template, the result is empty object.

this is my [gatsby-node](https://github.com/purplesfn/purplesfn-gatsby-prismic/blob/master/gatsby-node.js) and
this is my [post template](https://github.com/purplesfn/purplesfn-gatsby-prismic/blob/master/src/templates/post.js)

i dont understand why the props are empty and how to use it in posts

Very thx to everyone will help me!

---

FIXED,
the problem was looping over `nodes` and not over `edges`.
By looping on `edges`, i was able to retrieve `next` and `prev`.
Later with the pageContext I was able to use them in my post template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`props` can't be an empty object because you are destructuring it as `data` so assuming your post is being created correctly, I'd try something like:

```
const Post = ({ data, pageContext }) => {
  if (!data) return null
  const post = data.prismicPost
  console.log(data, pageContext)
```